# Image not binding in XAML (Xamarin User Control)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, data-binding, user-controls

I am creating a 'CardView' control which has an Image and two lines of text.
On my page, if I assign the values, the image renders, however if I use databinding expressions it does not work...

Here is the control:

```
public partial class CardView : Frame
{
    public CardView()
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(CardView), null, BindingMode.OneWay);

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SubtitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Subtitle), typeof(string), typeof(CardView), null, BindingMode.OneWay);

    public string Subtitle
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SubtitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SubtitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(CardView), null, BindingMode.OneWay);

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

Here is the XAML for the control:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <Image HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
           Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />

    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

    <Label Text="{Binding Subtitle}"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

In my viewmodel class:

```
public class SettingsPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SettingsPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        Title = "Title";
    }

    public string Subtitle => "Subtitle";
    public string Image => "icon.png";

}
```

Here is my XAML for the page where the binding fails:

```
<controls:CardView Title="No Bound Title" Subtitle="No Bound SubTitle" ImageSource="icon.png">
    </controls:CardView>

    <controls:CardView BindingContext="{Binding .}" Title="{Binding Title}" Subtitle="{Binding Subtitle}" ImageSource="{Binding Image}">
    </controls:CardView>
```

The first instance of the control renders correctly.
The second instance does not show the image.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your bindings do not work in the second scenario is because you set `BindingContext="{Binding .}"` on your control in *XAML*, which dismisses the effect of the `BindingContext = this` instruction in your control's constructor (that's why using such approach is a bad practice), rendering the bindings defined in the template invalid. More specifically, the source for the bindings is no longer the control itself, but rather your view-model. Now the `SettingsPageViewModel` happens to have `Title` and `Subtitle` properties, so those bindings should continue to work, but it does not contain an `ImageSource` property, so this binding will fail. You should be able to observe appropriate message in the output window.

I suggest you remove mentioned line from the constructor and use [template bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TemplateBinding/) in your control's template:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <Image HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
           Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" />
    <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Subtitle}"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

That way you are free to use the `BindingContext` on your control without affecting validity of bindings used in its template.

Comment: I have removed the 'BindingContext = this' and changed the 'Binding' to 'TemplateBinding' and I get 2 empty rendered controls. The binding doesn't work at all now.

Comment: That's weird. Are you getting any errors in the output window? And is the `StackLayout` nested inside a `ControlTemplate` templating your control?